# What is the difference between System.Configurations and CoreCompact..System.Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am writing my first application with .Net Core. I designed a multi layered application and there is a separate .Net Core class Library for Data Access Layer. When i try to read the connection string from the configuration file as we used to do with previous .net versions

```
 string connectionString =  Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDataBase"]);
```

However I figured that .Net core class library doesn't support for System.Configuration library. Therefore i added  CoreCompact..System.Configuration library using NPM and it compiled my application successfully

What is the difference between System.Configuration and CoreCompact..System.Configuration libraries?

Comment: Configurations in .Net core should be handled with IConfiguration. I never heard of that library you mentioned before. Can you provide a link?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration).

Comment: to learn the correct way to do configuration in .NET Core using the new configuration classes, see the docs https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html